# How to install whatweb on ubuntu?

Tags: package-management

I tried installing the **whatweb** package using aptitude. But after installation when I tried to use whatweb command, I receive the below error:

```
$ whatweb -h

Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /usr/bin/whatweb:37:in `<main>'
    1: from /home/host/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/home/host/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': cannot load such file -- whatweb (LoadError)
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt reinstall whatweb` and paste the output into your question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: Hi FedKad, save issue after reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get WhatWeb working on ubuntu. Here are the steps that I followed:

**Step1:** Open a terminal: Press Ctrl + Alt + T to open a new terminal window or search for "Terminal" in the Ubuntu Dash.

**Step2:** Update the package repository: Run the following command to update the package repository on your Ubuntu system:

```
sudo apt update
```

**Step3:** Install the required dependencies for WhatWeb

```
sudo apt install ruby ruby-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev
```

**Step4:** Install the "WhatWeb" tool manually using Git:

```
git clone https://github.com/urbanadventurer/WhatWeb.git
cd WhatWeb
sudo gem install bundler
bundle install
```

This will clone the WhatWeb repository from GitHub and install the necessary gems using Bundler.

**Step5:** Verify the installation by running the following command:

```
​whatweb --version
```

If WhatWeb is installed properly, you should see the version number displayed in the terminal.

Ref: https://www.techpond.in/how-install-whatweb-ubuntu